# How to create a generic "consecutive snackbars" component with React and Material UI?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, snackbar

The Material UI documentation has [a section about "Consecutive Snackbars"](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-snackbar/#consecutive-snackbars), but does not indicate how we could extract the logic to a generic component so we could use it in several places of our application.

I'm using React v18 and Material UI v5.

Answer (score 1):

A working example is to replace the "click" event handler of the [MUI documentation](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-snackbar/#consecutive-snackbars) (i.e. `handleClick`) with an effect depending on a passed prop (i.e. `content`, renamed `value`):

```
// src/Snack.tsx
import { Snackbar, SnackbarProps } from "@mui/material";
import React from "react";

type SnackContent = {
  key: number;
  value: React.ReactNode;
};

// Omit all props necessary for the consecutive snackbars logic
type SnackProps = Omit<
  SnackbarProps,
  "children" | "key" | "message" | "onClose" | "open" | "TransitionProps"
> & {
  content: SnackContent["value"];
};

export const Snack: React.FC<SnackProps> = ({
  // Passed `content` is actually the `SnackContent.value`
  content: value,
  ...otherProps
}) => {
  const [content, setContent] = React.useState<SnackContent>();
  const [pack, setPack] = React.useState<readonly SnackContent[]>([]);
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = React.useState<boolean>(false);

  const handleSnackClose = (
    event: React.SyntheticEvent | Event,
    reason?: string
  ) => reason !== "clickaway" && setIsOpen(false);

  const handleSnackExited = () => setContent(undefined);

  // Update content pack
  React.useEffect(() => {
    value && setPack((prev) => [...prev, { key: new Date().getTime(), value }]);
  }, [value]);

  // Handle consecutive snackbars https://mui.com/material-ui/react-snackbar/#consecutive-snackbars
  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (pack.length && !content) {
      // Set a new snack when we don't have an active one
      setContent({ ...pack[0] });
      setPack((prev) => prev.slice(1));
      setIsOpen(true);
    } else if (pack.length && content && isOpen) {
      // Close an active snack when a new one is added
      setIsOpen(false);
    }
  }, [pack, content, isOpen]);

  return (
    <Snackbar
      key={content?.key}
      open={isOpen}
      autoHideDuration={6000}
      onClose={handleSnackClose}
      TransitionProps={{ onExited: handleSnackExited }}
      {...otherProps}
    >
      {/* A "div" wrapper is required so `content.value` can be `null` */}
      <div>{content?.value}</div>
    </Snackbar>
  );
};
```

Usage:

```
// src/SomeComponent.tsx
import React from "react";
import { Snack } from "./Snack";

export const SomeComponent: React.FC = () => {
  const [snackContent, setSnackContent] = React.useState<React.ReactNode>();

  // The "hello world" text is wrapped with React.Fragment so the `Snack` component rerenders when its `content` prop value changes
  const handleTestClick = () => setSnackContent(<>"Hello, world!"</>);

  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={handleTestClick}>Test</button>
      <Snack
        content={snackContent}
        anchorOrigin={{ horizontal: "center", vertical: "bottom" }}
      />
    </>
  );
};
```

This works both on classic and touch desktops.

Here is [a code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/embed/material-ui-conecutive-snackbars-xf3o87?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark).

Comment: Great example. It's also possible to "queue" snackbars using state and setInterval --- https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/react18-mui5-queued-snackbar-messages-k9v6rw

Comment: @WesleyLeMahieu nice, thanks for sharing! I would however point out that [Material design](https://m1.material.io/components/snackbars-toasts.html#snackbars-toasts-usage) recommends to instantly trigger the disappearing animation of the previous snackbar (cf. the "Consecutive snackbars" section).