# How to create a consecutive snackbar/alert component with React and Material UI v5 in Javascript?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, alert, snackbar

I am trying to extract the logic of the Material UI v5 SnackbarAlert into a re-usable component. I have found a very [similar question answered recently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75484476/how-to-create-a-generic-consecutive-snackbars-component-with-react-and-materia), however my app is using JavaScript.

I've attempted to adapt this to JavaScript, but I am having issues with the component re-rendering multiple times upon open /close of the Alert Snackbar.

My code so far:

```
// src/AlertSnackbar.jsx
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import Snackbar from '@mui/material/Snackbar';
import MuiAlert from '@mui/material/Alert';

const Alert = React.forwardRef(function Alert(props, ref) {
  return <MuiAlert elevation={6} ref={ref} variant="filled" {...props} />;
});


export default function AlertSnackbar({message, ...otherProps}) {

  const [content, setContent] = useState(undefined);
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false)
  const [pack, setPack] = useState([])

  const handleClose = () => {
    setOpen(false);
  }

  //update content pack
  useEffect(()=> {
    message && setPack((prev) => [...prev, { message, key: new Date().getTime() }]);
  }, [message])

  //handle consecutive snackbars
  useEffect(() => {
    if (pack.length && !content) {
      //set a new snack when no active snack
      setContent({...pack[0]})
      setPack((prev)=> prev.slice(1))
      setOpen(true)
    } else if (pack.length && content && open) {
      //Close an active snack when a new one is added
      setOpen(false)
    }
  }, [pack, content, open])


  const handleExited = () => {
    setContent(undefined);
  };
  

  return (
    <Snackbar open={open} autoHideDuration={6000} onClose={handleClose} {...otherProps}
      TransitionProps={{ onExited: handleExited }} key={content?.key } 
    >
      <Alert onClose={handleClose} severity="success" sx={{ width: '100%' }}>
      <div>{content?.message}</div>
      </Alert>
    </Snackbar>
  )
}
```

Usage:

```
// src/SomeComponent.jsx
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { Button } from '@mui/material'
import AlertSnackbar from '../components/AlertSnackbar'

export default SomeComponent = () => {

  const [snackContent, setSnackContent] = useState(<></>)

  const handleTestClick = () => setSnackContent(<>Hello, world!</>);


  return (
    <>
    <Button onClick={handleTestClick}>Test</Button>
    <AlertSnackbar message={snackContent} anchorOrigin={{ horizontal: "center", vertical: "bottom" }} />
    </>
  )
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: May I ask what is the meaning 're-rendering multiple times'? I tried your cod and it worked fine.
The `AlertSnackbar` render three times when the `message` is changed from parent component. The renders are caused by: (1) `message` changed. (2) `pack` updated in the first useEffect. (3) `content` updated in the second useEffect. And the parent component, which is `SomeComponent ` in your example have renderred only 1 time.

Comment: @YellowD Thanks for this! So I inserted a console.log line in the parent and snackbar component, and each button click /close button press was logging out to the console several times...but inserting the same console.log into the linked question's sandcodebox snack component, it doesn't output the console.log multiple times, (just the once) so was wondering how I could manage to do this too but got stuck.

Comment: could you point the console.log position? I also try to insert console.log in the sandbox of the answer, the result is as the same as yours. Btw, it might trigger double render if you're using `strict mode`. This might make some confusion. You can comment the `<StrictMode>` JSX in `index.js` if you want to check it. The answer is using `strict mode` though, so I don't think it's the point.

Comment: @YellowD Oh I tried adding a console.log just beneath the state initialisation in the linked Q's sandbox's snack component and it does log quite a lot too . Also I have commented out Strictmode in my app.

Answer (score 0):

1. I see is that you're using a complex JSX element as the initial value for the snackContent state in SomeComponent. Instead, you should initialize it to an empty string or any other suitable initial value, like so:

```
const [snackContent, setSnackContent] = useState('');
```

2. You're setting open to false when it's called, but this doesn't clear the content state. Instead, you should also set content to undefined when the Snackbar is closed, like so:

```
const handleClose = () => {
      setOpen(false);
      setContent(undefined);
    };
```

3. The condition if (pack.length && content && open) doesn't cover the case where there are multiple items in the pack array. Instead, you should check if the pack array has changed, like so:

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (pack.length && !content) {
    setContent({ ...pack[0] });
    setPack(prev => prev.slice(1));
    setOpen(true);
  } else if (pack.length && content && open && pack[0].key !== content.key) {
    setOpen(false);
  }
}, [pack, content, open]);
```

With these changes, your code should work correctly. Here's the complete AlertSnackbar component:

```
// src/AlertSnackbar.jsx
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import Snackbar from '@mui/material/Snackbar';
import MuiAlert from '@mui/material/Alert';

const Alert = React.forwardRef(function Alert(props, ref) {
  return <MuiAlert elevation={6} ref={ref} variant="filled" {...props} />;
});

export default function AlertSnackbar({ message, ...otherProps }) {
  const [content, setContent] = useState(undefined);
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
  const [pack, setPack] = useState([]);

  const handleClose = () => {
    setOpen(false);
    setContent(undefined);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    message && setPack(prev => [...prev, { message, key: new Date().getTime() }]);
  }, [message]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (pack.length && !content) {
      setContent({ ...pack[0] });
      setPack(prev => prev.slice(1));
      setOpen(true);
    } else if (pack.length && content && open && pack[0].key !== content.key) {
      setOpen(false);
    }
  }, [pack, content, open]);

  const handleExited = () => {
    setContent(undefined);
  };

  return (
    <Snackbar
      open={open}
      autoHideDuration={6000}
      onClose={handleClose}
      {...otherProps}
      TransitionProps={{ onExited: handleExited }}
      key={content?.key}
    >
      <Alert onClose={handleClose} severity="success" sx={{ width: '100%' }}>
        <div>{content?.message}</div>
      </Alert>
    </Snackbar>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thank you Pavel for this! I tried implementing your suggestions and testing it out with my parent component but there is still a bug in my code - Pressing the open button, the alert appears, but after it disappears, pressing the open button again nothing happens. Do you think there is an issue with how I pass in the message prop to the child element? Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I could get the consecutive alert snackbar to work if I wrap the alert message with React.Fragment. Using just a string did not work.

Triggering the snackbar on another page like so:

```
//src/SomeComponent.jsx
const [snackContent, setSnackContent] = useState("")

const handleBtnOne= () => setSnackContent("Hello, world!"); //doesn't work
const handleBtnTwo = () => setSnackContent(<>Goodbye World</>); //does work

return (
<>
<Button onClick={handleBtnOne}>One</Button>
<Button onClick={handleBtnTwo }>Two</Button>
<AlertSnackbar message={snackContent} />
</>
)
```

But I am unsure if using React.fragment snippets like this is valid?

```
//src/AlertComponent.jsx
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import Snackbar from '@mui/material/Snackbar';
import MuiAlert from '@mui/material/Alert';


const Alert = React.forwardRef(function Alert(props, ref) {
  return <MuiAlert elevation={6} ref={ref} variant="filled" {...props} />;
});


export default function AlertSnackbar({message, ...otherProps}) {

  const [content, setContent] = useState(undefined);
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false)
  const [pack, setPack] = useState([])

  const handleClose = () => {
    setOpen(false);
    setContent(undefined)
  }

  //update content pack
  useEffect(()=> {
    message && setPack((prev) => [...prev, { message, key: new Date().getTime()}]);}, 
  [message])


  //handle consecutive snackbars
  useEffect(() => {
    if (pack.length && !content) {
      //set a new snack when no active snack
      setContent({...pack[0]})
      setPack((prev)=> prev.slice(1))
      setOpen(true)
    } else if (pack.length && content && open && pack[0].key!==content.key) {
      //Close an active snack when a new one is added
      setOpen(false)
    }
  }, [pack, content, open])


  const handleExited = () => {
    setContent(undefined);
  };
  

  return (
    <Snackbar open={open} autoHideDuration={6000} onClose={handleClose} 
      TransitionProps={{ onExited: handleExited }} key={content?.key } 
    >
      <Alert onClose={handleClose} severity="success" sx={{ width: '100%' }}>
      <div>{content?.message}</div>
      </Alert>
    </Snackbar>
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Material UI has a working example of this (without Alert) but you can add the Alert to it and it works just fine.

Reference Link: https://mui.com/material-ui/react-snackbar/#consecutive-snackbars

Here is a Next.js client component example:

```
'use client';
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { Alert, Button, Slide, SlideProps, Snackbar } from '@mui/material';

type TransitionProps = Omit<SlideProps, 'direction'>;

const SlideTransition = (props: TransitionProps) => <Slide {...props} direction="up" />;

export interface SnackbarMessage {
  message: string;
  key: number;
}

export interface State {
  open: boolean;
  snackPack: readonly SnackbarMessage[];
  messageInfo?: SnackbarMessage;
}

const Alerts = (}) => {
  const [snackPack, setSnackPack] = useState<readonly SnackbarMessage[]>([]);
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
  const [messageInfo, setMessageInfo] = useState<SnackbarMessage | undefined>(undefined);

  const handleClick = (message: string) => () => {
    setSnackPack(prev => [...prev, { key: new Date().getTime(), message }]);
  };

  const onClose = () => {
    setOpen(false);
  };

  const handleExited = () => {
    setMessageInfo(undefined);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (snackPack.length && !messageInfo) {
      // Set a new snack when we don't have an active one
      setMessageInfo({ ...snackPack[0] });
      setSnackPack(prev => prev.slice(1));
      setOpen(true);
    } else if (snackPack.length && messageInfo && open) {
      // Close an active snack when a new one is added
      setOpen(false);
    }
  }, [snackPack, messageInfo, open]);

  return (
    <>
      <Button onClick={handleClick('Message A')}>Show message A</Button>
      <Button onClick={handleClick('Message B')}>Show message B</Button>
      <Snackbar
        TransitionComponent={SlideTransition}
        TransitionProps={{ onExited: handleExited }}
        anchorOrigin={{ horizontal: 'center', vertical: 'bottom' }}
        key={messageInfo ? messageInfo.key : undefined}
        message={messageInfo ? messageInfo.message : undefined}
        onClose={onClose}
        open={open}
      >
        {messageInfo ? (
          <Alert elevation={2} icon={false} onClose={onClose} severity="success">
            {messageInfo ? messageInfo.message : undefined}
          </Alert>
        ) : undefined}
      </Snackbar>
    </>
  );
};

export default Alerts;
```